# Mongodb and Celery "pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command createIndexes requires authentication"

Tags: python, mongodb, celery

I am working Celery with Mongodb( as backend and as a broker).
I follow this tutorial on how to set them up: https://skillachie.com/2013/06/15/intro-celery-and-mongodb/

When I have the security enable on the /etc/mongod.conf file like this:

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

and I call the .get() to get the results of the tasks that I have set up I get this error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/celeryProject/celeryProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 323, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'collection'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/celeryProject/celeryProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 169, in get
    no_ack=no_ack,
  File "/home/celeryProject/celeryProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 229, in wait_for
    meta = self.get_task_meta(task_id)
  File "/home/celeryProject/celeryProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 307, in get_task_meta
    meta = self._get_task_meta_for(task_id)
  File "/home/celeryProject/celeryProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/mongodb.py", line 158, in _get_task_meta_for
    obj = self.collection.find_one({'_id': task_id})
  File "/home/celeryProject/celeryProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 325, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "/home/celeryProject/celeryProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/mongodb.py", line 246, in collection
    collection.ensure_index('date_done', background='true')
  File "/home/celeryProject/celeryProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2028, in ensure_index
    self.__create_index(keys, kwargs, session=None)
  File "/home/celeryProject/celeryProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1894, in __create_index
    session=session)
  File "/home/celeryProject/celeryProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 250, in _command
    user_fields=user_fields)
  File "/home/celeryProject/celeryProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 613, in command
    user_fields=user_fields)
  File "/home/celeryProject/celeryProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 167, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "/home/celeryProject/celeryProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 159, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command createIndexes requires authentication
```

But when I disable the security it is working!

I also tried to change the roles on the user on mongodb and nothing happened.

Also, I have tried to log in with that way:

```
BROKER_URL = 'mongodb://tester:123456@178.128.250.181:27017/test?authSource=admin'

celery = Celery('EOD_TASKS',broker=BROKER_URL)
```

Is this a security problem or I can ignore it and move on?

Answer (score 2):

if i'm not mistaken, using `authorization: enabled` means you need to setup a user/pass to login in order to query the mongodb. by default it is left wide open, which is a security consideration

Comment: Yes, the same thing I believe. But still, I can not understand what is the problem with Celery.

Comment: the last line reads `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command createIndexes requires authentication` mongo is telling celery "you need to login"

Comment: I login like that:
BROKER_URL = 'mongodb://"username":"pass"myIP":27017/test?authSource=admin'


celery = Celery('EOD_TASKS',broker=BROKER_URL)

Comment: Odd. Perhaps a permissions issue - does user have privileges to `createIndexes`?

Comment: I tried to give them root privileges and it did not worked. I will try the createIndexes to be sure.